# Depend on the popup's table data, parent's table data showing item is different

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I have a popup modal like this one.
[image]

When I click 'ADD' button, all the data from popup's table is shown at the table of the parent's. Like this one.
[image]

The problem is that I don't want to show the plus sign "+", if there is no data in textbox2s.
Here is the code at popup.js

```
function add_to_prent_table(){

var popupTable = [];
var i = 0;

$('#testing > tbody > tr').each(function () {

    popupTable[i] = [
        $(this).find("#test_number").val(),
        $(this).find("#type_1").val(),
        $(this).find("#type_2").val(),
        $(this).find("#place_1").val(),
        $(this).find("#place_2").val(),
        ];
    i++;

    var newRow = '<tr>'+
    '<td id ="td_center">'+
        $(this).find("#test_piece_number").val() +
    '</td>'+
    '<td id ="td_center">'+
        $(this).find("#type_1").val() + ' + ' +
        $(this).find("#type_2").val() +
    '</td>'+
    '<td id ="td_center">'+
        $(this).find("#place_1").val() + ' + ' +
        $(this).find("#place_2").val() +
    '</td>'+
    '</tr>';

    $('#testing_parent tbody').append(newRow);
});
```

}

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's messy but you can replace the first `' + '` with this:

```
$(this).find("#type_2").val() ? ' + ' : ''
```

And replace the second `' + '` with

```
$(this).find("#place_2").val() ? ' + ' : ''
```

Basically you're looking to see if #type_2 and #place_2 have values. If they do, add a ' + '. If not, add nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
function add_to_prent_table() {

var popupTable = [];
var i = 0;

$('#testing > tbody > tr').each(function () {

    var testNumber = $(this).find("#test_number").val();
    var firstType = $(this).find("#type_1").val();
    var secondType = $(this).find("#type_2").val();
    var firstPlace = $(this).find("#place_1").val();
    var secondPlace = $(this).find("#place_2").val();

    popupTable[i] = [
        testNumber,
        firstType,
        secondType,
        firstPlace,
        secondPlace,
    ];

    i++;

    var newRow = '<tr>' +
        '<td id ="td_center">' +
        $(this).find("#test_piece_number").val() +
        '</td>' +
        '<td id ="td_center">' +
            firstType + secondType ? (' + ' + secondType) : '' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td id ="td_center">' +
            firstPlace + secondPlace ? (' + ' + secondPlace) : '' +
        '</td>' +
        '</tr>';

    $('#testing_parent tbody').append(newRow);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add condition before adding plus sign like below,

```
 var newRow = '<tr>'+
    '<td id ="td_center">'+
        $(this).find("#test_piece_number").val() +
    '</td>'+
    '<td id ="td_center">'+
        $(this).find("#type_1").val() 
        if($(this).find("#type_2").val() != "")
        {
            ' + ' + $(this).find("#type_2").val()
        }
    '</td>'+
    '<td id ="td_center">'+
        $(this).find("#place_1").val() 
        if($(this).find("#place_2").val() != "")
        {
            ' + ' + $(this).find("#place_2").val()
        }
    '</td>'+
    '</tr>';
```